# how to use `filterEditorValueMap`

Tags: smartclient

[image: Permission ListGrid]

I have a listgrid that has a custom column **PermissionLevel** to illustrate the value of the column **Value**. I want to give users the ability to filter. So..

1. I set the `filterEditorType` as "SelectItem"
2. populated it with the different graph lengths
3. and set each of the values equal to the corresponding values in **Value**

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I was thinking that if I set the `filterEditorValueMap` so that it would search for values in the column **Value** it would work the way I want it to, but no luck so far.  Perhaps I just don't know how to set `filterEditorValueMap`

Thanks in advance @claudiobosticco :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you gave little context, like the code of the grid and/or a complete mockup of the filter appearance you need.

But, if I understood correctly your use case, a sample like this may be right for it:

```
isc.ListGrid.create({
    ID: "countryList",
    width: 500, height: 300, alternateRecordStyles: true,
    dataSource: worldDS,
    fields: [
        {
            type: "image", imageURLPrefix: "flags/16/", imageURLSuffix: ".png",
            name: "countryCode", title: "Code", width: 50,
            filterEditorType: "SelectItem",
            filterEditorValueMap: {"US": "US", "CA": "CA"},
            filterEditorProperties: {
                formatValue: function (value, record, form, item) {
                    return form.imgHTML("flags/16/" + value + ".png")
                },
                pickListFields: [
                    {name: "countryCode", type: "image", imageURLPrefix: "flags/16/", imageURLSuffix: ".png"}
                ]
            }
        },
        {name: "countryName", title: "Country"},
        {name: "capital", title: "Capital"},
        {name: "continent", title: "Continent"}
    ],
    autoFetchData: true,
    showFilterEditor: true
})
```

You may cut'n'paste it in a SmartClient showCase sample like [filterSample](http://www.smartclient.com/#filter)

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this isn't what I need.. when I get some free time I'll try to update my post with specific code